# Error de compilación, código VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, compilacion, referencias

Estoy realizando un proyecto, sin embargo, al correr me sale un mensaje: Biblioteca o referencia no encontrado, pero al correr en otras máquinas si se ejecuta.

Estoy intentando utilizar Lcase en un userform para hacer una búsqueda inteligencia, he buscado en internet la solución, pero no lo encuentro.

Me podrían ayudar indicando como solucionar: buscar, descargar e instalar esta referencia
Esperando recibir respuestas, me despido.
Franklin

Código:

```
Private Sub TxtNombre_Change()
Dim y As Integer
Dim fila As Integer
Dim texto As String
Dim final As Integer

y = 0

With frm_Consultas.lbx_Examenes
    .Clear
    final = UltimoRegistro(Hoja5, 1, 1) - 1

For fila = 2 To final
        texto = Hoja5.Cells(fila, 3).Value

        If LCase(texto) Like "*" & LCase(Me.TxtNombre.Value) & "*" Then
        .AddItem
       .List(y, 0) = Hoja5.Cells(fila, 1)
       .List(y, 1) = Hoja5.Cells(fila, 2)
       .List(y, 2) = Hoja5.Cells(fila, 3)
       .List(y, 3) = Hoja5.Cells(fila, 4)
       .List(y, 4) = Hoja5.Cells(fila, 5)
       .List(y, 5) = Hoja5.Cells(fila, 6)
       .List(y, 6) = FormatNumber(Hoja5.Cells(fila, 7), 2)
       .List(y, 7) = FormatPercent(Hoja5.Cells(fila, 8))
       .List(y, 8) = FormatNumber(Hoja5.Cells(fila, 9), 2)
       .List(y, 9) = FormatNumber(Hoja5.Cells(fila, 10), 2)
          y = y + 1
        End If
Next fila

End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

En tu Excel ve al editor VBA y al menú Herramientas --> Referencias. Aparecen las referencias disponibles y, marcadas con el check, las referencias que están activadas para utilizarse. En alguna de esas referencias aparecerá el nombre de dicha referencia y la palabra "FALTA". Esa es la referencia que necesitas instalar.